# MVC method cycles through array but only displays values for last item in array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller method that cycles through my "sites" database table but currently it only posts the content for the last item in the array and posts it the same amount of times as sites in the database.

Here is a look at my view

```
  @foreach (Site s in sites)
        {

            <tr style="color:black">
                @foreach (var col in Model.OffReportColumns)
                {
                    <th>@col</th>
                }
            </tr>

            foreach (var row in Model.OffReportRows)
            {
                <tr style="color:black">
                    @foreach (var cell in row)
                    {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }


            foreach (var row in Model.OffReporTotal)
            {
                <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                    @foreach (var cell in row)
                    {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                    }
                </tr>

            }
        }
```

And here is my controller

```
 namespace PIC_Program_1._0.Controllers
{
    public class SummaryReportController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = GetSummaryReport();
            return View("Index", model);   
        }

        private SummaryReportModel GetSummaryReport()
        {
            PIC_Program_1_0Context db = new PIC_Program_1_0Context();
            var items = db.Items.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();
            var components = db.Components.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();
            var parts = db.Parts.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();
            List<Site> sites = db.Sites.ToList();

            //variables
            float partcost = 0;
            float compcost = 0;
            float complastcost = 0;
            float compretail = 0;
            float itemcost = 0;
            float itemlastcost = 0;
            float itemretail = 0;
            float opartcost = 0;
            float ocompcost = 0;
            float ocomplastcost = 0;
            float ocompretail = 0;
            float oitemcost = 0;
            float oitemlastcost = 0;
            float oitemretail = 0;
            float lcompcost = 0;
            float litemcost = 0;
            float locompcost = 0;
            float loitemcost = 0;
            float tools = 0;
            float otools = 0;
            float total = 0;
            float ltotal = 0;
            float ostotal = 0;
            float ofltotal = 0;
            float pc6 = 0;
            float pr6 = 0;
            float pc7 = 0;
            float pr7 = 0;
            float pc8 = 0;
            float pr8 = 0;
            float pc9 = 0;
            float pr9 = 0;
            float opc6 = 0;
            //float opr6 = 0;
            float opc7 = 0;
            //float opr7 = 0;
            float opc8 = 0;
            //float opr8 = 0;
            float opc9 = 0;
            //float opr9 = 0;
            float pro = 0;
            float pco = 0;
            float plo = 0;
            //float opro = 0;
            float opco = 0;
            //float oplo = 0;

            //osi items
            float[] osiItemCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiLoItemCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiItemLastCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            //float[] osiItemRetail;

            //osi components
            float[] osiCompCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiLoCompCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiCompLastCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            //float[] osiCompRetail;

            //osi parts
            float[] osiOpc6 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpr6 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpc7 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpr7 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpc8 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpr8 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpc9 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpr9 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpco = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOpro = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiOplo = new float[sites.Count + 1];

            //OSI TOTALS
            float[] osiPartCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiTools = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiTotal = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            float[] osiFltotal = new float[sites.Count + 1];
            //float[] osiPartCost;


            foreach (var p in parts)
            {
                if (p.PartID.StartsWith("6"))
                {
                    pc6 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    pr6 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                    //opc6 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    //opr6 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
                }

                else if (p.PartID.StartsWith("7"))
                {
                    pc7 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    pr7 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                    //opc7 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    //opr7 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
                }

                else if (p.PartID.StartsWith("8"))
                {
                    pc8 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    pr8 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                    //opc8 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    //opr8 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
                }

                else if (p.PartID.StartsWith("9"))
                {
                    pc9 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    pr9 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                    //opc9 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    //opr9 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
                }

                else
                {
                    pco += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    pro += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                    //opco += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                    //opro += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;

                    plo += p.On_Hand * p.LastCostCdn;
                    //oplo += p.OffSiteCount * p.LastCostCdn;
                }
            }

            foreach (var c in components)
            {
                // New Average Cost Valuation = (pc6 + pc7 + pc8)
                partcost = pc6 + pc7 + pc8;
                opartcost = opc6 + opc7 + opc8;
                tools = pc9 + pco;
                otools = opc9 + opco;

                //Add Labour
                compcost += c.On_Hand * c.cost(1, false, false);
                lcompcost += c.On_Hand * c.cost(1, false, true);

                complastcost += c.cost(c.On_Hand, true, false);
                compretail += c.On_Hand * c.PricePerUnit;

                ocompcost += c.OffSiteCount * c.cost(1, false, false);
                locompcost += c.OffSiteCount * c.cost(1, false, true);

                ocomplastcost += c.cost(c.OffSiteCount, true, false);
                ocompretail += c.OffSiteCount * c.PricePerUnit;
            }

            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                itemcost += i.On_Hand * i.cost(1, false, false);
                litemcost += i.On_Hand * i.cost(1, false, true);

                itemlastcost += i.cost(i.On_Hand, true, false);
                itemretail += i.On_Hand * (float)i.PricePerUnit;

                oitemcost += i.OffSiteCount * i.cost(1, false, false);
                loitemcost += i.OffSiteCount * i.cost(1, false, true);

                oitemlastcost += i.cost(i.OffSiteCount, true, false);
                oitemretail += i.OffSiteCount * (float)i.PricePerUnit;

                //on Site Parts Total valu 
                total = partcost + compcost + itemcost;
                ltotal = partcost + lcompcost + litemcost;

                //Off Site Parts Total valu 
                ostotal = opartcost + ocompcost + oitemcost;
                ofltotal = opartcost + locompcost + loitemcost;
            }


            foreach (Site s in sites)
            {
                foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
                {

                    if (d.itemID != null)
                    {

                        osiItemCost[s.ID] = d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, false);
                        osiLoItemCost[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, true);

                        osiItemLastCost[s.ID] += db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(d.qty, true, false);
                        //osiItemRetail[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;

                    }
                    if (d.componentID != null)
                    {
                        osiPartCost[s.ID] = osiOpc6[s.ID] + osiOpc7[s.ID] + osiOpc8[s.ID];
                        osiTools[s.ID] = osiOpc9[s.ID] + osiOpco[s.ID];

                        osiCompCost[s.ID] = d.qty * db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, false);
                        osiLoCompCost[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, true);

                        osiCompLastCost[s.ID] += db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().cost(d.qty, true, false);
                        //osiCompRetail[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                    }
                    if (d.partID != null)
                    {
                        if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("6"))                     
                        {
                            osiOpc6[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                            osiOpr6[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                        }
                        else if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("7"))
                        {
                            osiOpc7[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                            osiOpr7[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                        }
                        else if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("8"))
                        {
                            osiOpc8[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                            osiOpr8[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                        }
                        else if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("9"))
                        {
                            osiOpc9[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                            osiOpr9[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            osiOpco[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                            osiOpro[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;

                            osiOplo[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().LastCostCdn;
                        }

                    }

                    //Off Site Parts Total valu
                    osiTotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID];
                    osiFltotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiLoCompCost[s.ID] + osiLoItemCost[s.ID];

                }
            }

            var model = new SummaryReportModel()
            {
                Title = "Valuation",
                ReportTitle = "Valuation - Summary Report",
                OffReportTitle = "Valuation - Off Site Parts"
            };

            model.Tital = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
                 {
                      "Valuation - Main Inventory",
                 },
            };
            model.ValuationColumns = new List<string>()
            {
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
            model.ValuationRows = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    partcost.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    partcost.ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    pc6.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    pc6.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    pc7.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    pc7.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    pc8.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    pc8.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Tools",
                    "",
                    "",
                    tools.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    tools.ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    pc9.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    pc9.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    pco.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    pco.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Components",
                    "",
                    "",
                    compcost.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    lcompcost.ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Items",
                    "",
                    "",
                    itemcost.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    litemcost.ToString("C2")
                },
        };

            //totlal class

            model.Total = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    total.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    ltotal.ToString("C2")
                },
            };

            model.SecondTital = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
                 {
                  "Valuation - Off Site Parts"
                 },
            };

            List<SummaryReportModel> a = new List<SummaryReportModel>(); // this is what you'll return to the view

            foreach (Site s in sites)
            {
             SummaryReportModel y = new SummaryReportModel();
             foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
             {           
            y.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()
            {
                s.Name,
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
              y.OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>()
            {

                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Tools",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                     "",
                     "",
                    osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),

                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Components",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiLoCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Items",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiLoItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
            };
            y.OffReporTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiTotal[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiFltotal[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
            };

       }
        a.Add(y);
 }

            //return View(a);

            model.osiGrandTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "OSI Grand Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ostotal.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    ofltotal.ToString("C2")
                },
            };


            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is part of my "Sites" and "OffSiteItemDetails" table to show the structure

**Sites db**

[image: sites db]

**OffSiteItemDetails db**

[image: OffSiteItemDetails]

I want it to cycle through and post the values for each site (it does this through (s.ID).) It currently cycles through but it just posts the data for the last s.Id (site Id) in the table, and it does this 5 times (There are 5 sites). I want it to separate and post the data for each site when it cycles through and I am just not sure how to do that

Here is my model class

```
 public class SummaryReportModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
        public string OffReportTitle { get; set; }
        public List<string> ValuationColumns { get; set; }
        public List<string> OffReportColumns { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> ValuationRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> OffReportRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Total { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> OffReporTotal { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Tital { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> SecondTital { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> osiGrandTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you analyzed to make sure your data for 'sites' is correct before it hits the data grooming methods?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes I have. It's correct.. I just can't figure out how to create the 5 tables for the 5 sites rather than 5 tables for the last site in array

Comment: Can you post the model? My suspicion is that you're setting the value of the same property five times. Each iteration in the loop will need to have it's own object. For example I would expect to see obj_A with a List<property> x...in your code you should have foreach(var item in myCollection){ var y = new property;//set values then...obj_a.x.Add(y)}

Comment: "It currently cycles through but it just posts the data for the last s.Id" don't initialize the ``model.OffReportColumns`` and ``model.OffReportRows`` for each site, but use ``model.OffReportRows.Add(...)`` instead. And delete the foreach Site in the view

Comment: @BillRuhl Thats not the issue, I have tested that. I'm pretty sure the issue is because I don't "return model" until after the looping is done. And at that point the values would equal the last value in array. I'm just not sure how to return it after each cycle through

Comment: @chris I don't think my comment was clear. You're returning one model. Instead you need to return ether a list of models or a model that has a list of your tables. Try this...var x = new List<myModelType>(); then in the loop create var y = new myModelType(); populate the model then the last statement before exiting the loop should be x.Add(y); return the List<myModelType> to the view then you can iterate through the list of models to render the tables.

Comment: @BillRuhl Okay I kinda see what you mean I think. But still a little confused about things. I have edited my question to have your suggestions in it. Can you identify if I put them in the right spot? And I was a little confused by "return the List<myModelType>" and how I should go about doing that

Comment: @chris What is the type of your model? For example in the view I see you're looping over a collection of "sites". What is the exact type of the model that is being passed to the view? I know it's a custom type of some kind...if you can post the model class that would be an enormous help. Your model has properties called "OffReportColumns " and "OffReportRows " so each iteration of the sites collection should create a new model, set the values for OffReportColumns " and "OffReportRows" then add the model to a list with the type of your model.. new List<modelType>(); You're on the right track!

Comment: @BillRuhl Thanks Bill. I added my model class to the question now

Comment: @BillRuhl I also updated my question with the proper values that you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you'll need to declare the model as a list

```
@model List<PIC_Program_1._0.Models.SummaryReportModel>
```

Your controller should look like this:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", GetSummaryReport());
    }

    private List<SummaryReportModel> GetSummaryReport()
    {
        PIC_Program_1_0Context db = new PIC_Program_1_0Context();
        var items = db.Items.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();
        var components = db.Components.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();
        var parts = db.Parts.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();
        List<Site> sites = db.Sites.ToList();

        //variables
        float partcost = 0;
        float compcost = 0;
        float complastcost = 0;
        float compretail = 0;
        float itemcost = 0;
        float itemlastcost = 0;
        float itemretail = 0;
        float opartcost = 0;
        float ocompcost = 0;
        float ocomplastcost = 0;
        float ocompretail = 0;
        float oitemcost = 0;
        float oitemlastcost = 0;
        float oitemretail = 0;
        float lcompcost = 0;
        float litemcost = 0;
        float locompcost = 0;
        float loitemcost = 0;
        float tools = 0;
        float otools = 0;
        float total = 0;
        float ltotal = 0;
        float ostotal = 0;
        float ofltotal = 0;
        float pc6 = 0;
        float pr6 = 0;
        float pc7 = 0;
        float pr7 = 0;
        float pc8 = 0;
        float pr8 = 0;
        float pc9 = 0;
        float pr9 = 0;
        float opc6 = 0;
        //float opr6 = 0;
        float opc7 = 0;
        //float opr7 = 0;
        float opc8 = 0;
        //float opr8 = 0;
        float opc9 = 0;
        //float opr9 = 0;
        float pro = 0;
        float pco = 0;
        float plo = 0;
        //float opro = 0;
        float opco = 0;
        //float oplo = 0;

        //osi items
        float[] osiItemCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiLoItemCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiItemLastCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        //float[] osiItemRetail;

        //osi components
        float[] osiCompCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiLoCompCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiCompLastCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        //float[] osiCompRetail;

        //osi parts
        float[] osiOpc6 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpr6 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpc7 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpr7 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpc8 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpr8 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpc9 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpr9 = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpco = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOpro = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiOplo = new float[sites.Count + 1];

        //OSI TOTALS
        float[] osiPartCost = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiTools = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiTotal = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        float[] osiFltotal = new float[sites.Count + 1];
        //float[] osiPartCost;


        foreach (var p in parts)
        {
            if (p.PartID.StartsWith("6"))
            {
                pc6 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                pr6 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                //opc6 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                //opr6 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
            }

            else if (p.PartID.StartsWith("7"))
            {
                pc7 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                pr7 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                //opc7 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                //opr7 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
            }

            else if (p.PartID.StartsWith("8"))
            {
                pc8 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                pr8 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                //opc8 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                //opr8 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
            }

            else if (p.PartID.StartsWith("9"))
            {
                pc9 += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                pr9 += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                //opc9 += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                //opr9 += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;
            }

            else
            {
                pco += p.On_Hand * p.AverageCostCdn;
                pro += p.On_Hand * p.PricePerUnit;

                //opco += p.OffSiteCount * p.AverageCostCdn;
                //opro += p.OffSiteCount * p.PricePerUnit;

                plo += p.On_Hand * p.LastCostCdn;
                //oplo += p.OffSiteCount * p.LastCostCdn;
            }
        }

        foreach (var c in components)
        {
            // New Average Cost Valuation = (pc6 + pc7 + pc8)
            partcost = pc6 + pc7 + pc8;
            opartcost = opc6 + opc7 + opc8;
            tools = pc9 + pco;
            otools = opc9 + opco;

            //Add Labour
            compcost += c.On_Hand * c.cost(1, false, false);
            lcompcost += c.On_Hand * c.cost(1, false, true);

            complastcost += c.cost(c.On_Hand, true, false);
            compretail += c.On_Hand * c.PricePerUnit;

            ocompcost += c.OffSiteCount * c.cost(1, false, false);
            locompcost += c.OffSiteCount * c.cost(1, false, true);

            ocomplastcost += c.cost(c.OffSiteCount, true, false);
            ocompretail += c.OffSiteCount * c.PricePerUnit;
        }

        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            itemcost += i.On_Hand * i.cost(1, false, false);
            litemcost += i.On_Hand * i.cost(1, false, true);

            itemlastcost += i.cost(i.On_Hand, true, false);
            itemretail += i.On_Hand * (float)i.PricePerUnit;

            oitemcost += i.OffSiteCount * i.cost(1, false, false);
            loitemcost += i.OffSiteCount * i.cost(1, false, true);

            oitemlastcost += i.cost(i.OffSiteCount, true, false);
            oitemretail += i.OffSiteCount * (float)i.PricePerUnit;

            //on Site Parts Total valu 
            total = partcost + compcost + itemcost;
            ltotal = partcost + lcompcost + litemcost;

            //Off Site Parts Total valu 
            ostotal = opartcost + ocompcost + oitemcost;
            ofltotal = opartcost + locompcost + loitemcost;
        }


        foreach (Site s in sites)
        {
            foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
            {

                if (d.itemID != null)
                {

                    osiItemCost[s.ID] = d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, false);
                    osiLoItemCost[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, true);

                    osiItemLastCost[s.ID] += db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(d.qty, true, false);
                    //osiItemRetail[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;

                }
                if (d.componentID != null)
                {
                    osiPartCost[s.ID] = osiOpc6[s.ID] + osiOpc7[s.ID] + osiOpc8[s.ID];
                    osiTools[s.ID] = osiOpc9[s.ID] + osiOpco[s.ID];

                    osiCompCost[s.ID] = d.qty * db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, false);
                    osiLoCompCost[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, true);

                    osiCompLastCost[s.ID] += db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().cost(d.qty, true, false);
                    //osiCompRetail[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Components.Where(x => x.ID == d.componentID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                }
                if (d.partID != null)
                {
                    if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("6"))
                    {
                        osiOpc6[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                        osiOpr6[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                    }
                    else if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("7"))
                    {
                        osiOpc7[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                        osiOpr7[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                    }
                    else if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("8"))
                    {
                        osiOpc8[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                        osiOpr8[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                    }
                    else if (db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PartID.StartsWith("9"))
                    {
                        osiOpc9[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                        osiOpr9[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        osiOpco[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().AverageCostCdn;
                        osiOpro[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().PricePerUnit;

                        osiOplo[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == d.partID).FirstOrDefault().LastCostCdn;
                    }

                }

                //Off Site Parts Total valu
                osiTotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID];
                osiFltotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiLoCompCost[s.ID] + osiLoItemCost[s.ID];

            }
        }

        // I moved this inside the foreach (Site s in sites) loop
        //        var model = new SummaryReportModel()
        //        {
        //            Title = "Valuation",
        //            ReportTitle = "Valuation - Summary Report",
        //            OffReportTitle = "Valuation - Off Site Parts"
        //        };

        //        model.Tital = new List<List<string>>()
        //    {
        //         new List<string>()
        //         {
        //              "Valuation - Main Inventory",
        //         },
        //    };
        //        model.ValuationColumns = new List<string>()
        //    {
        //        "",
        //        "",
        //        "",
        //        "Average Cost",
        //        "",
        //        "",
        //        "Average Cost (With labour)"
        //    };
        //        model.ValuationRows = new List<List<string>>()
        //    {
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "Parts",
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            partcost.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            partcost.ToString("C2")
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "",
        //            "600000 series",
        //            pc6.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "600000 series",
        //            pc6.ToString("C2"),
        //            ""
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "",
        //            "700000 series",
        //            pc7.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "700000 series",
        //            pc7.ToString("C2"),
        //            ""
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "",
        //            "800000 series",
        //            pc8.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "800000 series",
        //            pc8.ToString("C2"),
        //            ""
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "Tools",
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            tools.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            tools.ToString("C2")
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "",
        //            "900000 series",
        //            pc9.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "900000 series",
        //            pc9.ToString("C2"),
        //            ""
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "",
        //            "Other",
        //            pco.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "Other",
        //            pco.ToString("C2"),
        //            ""
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "Components",
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            compcost.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            lcompcost.ToString("C2")
        //        },
        //        new List<string>()
        //        {
        //            "Items",
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            itemcost.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            litemcost.ToString("C2")
        //        },
        //};

        //        //totlal class

        //        model.Total = new List<List<string>>()
        //    {
        //         new List<string>()
        //      {
        //            "Total",
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            total.ToString("C2"),
        //            "",
        //            "",
        //            ltotal.ToString("C2")
        //        },
        //    };

        //        model.SecondTital = new List<List<string>>()
        //    {
        //         new List<string>()
        //         {
        //          "Valuation - Off Site Parts"
        //         },
        //    };

        List<SummaryReportModel> models = new List<SummaryReportModel>(); // this is what you'll return to the view
        foreach (Site s in sites)
        {
            SummaryReportModel model = new SummaryReportModel();
            model.Tital = new List<List<string>>()
                {
                     new List<string>()
                     {
                          "Valuation - Main Inventory",
                     },
                };
            model.ValuationColumns = new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "Average Cost",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "Average Cost (With labour)"
                };
            model.ValuationRows = new List<List<string>>()
                {
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Parts",
                        "",
                        "",
                        partcost.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        partcost.ToString("C2")
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "",
                        "600000 series",
                        pc6.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "600000 series",
                        pc6.ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "",
                        "700000 series",
                        pc7.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "700000 series",
                        pc7.ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "",
                        "800000 series",
                        pc8.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "800000 series",
                        pc8.ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Tools",
                        "",
                        "",
                        tools.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        tools.ToString("C2")
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "",
                        "900000 series",
                        pc9.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "900000 series",
                        pc9.ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "",
                        "Other",
                        pco.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "Other",
                        pco.ToString("C2"),
                        ""
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Components",
                        "",
                        "",
                        compcost.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        lcompcost.ToString("C2")
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Items",
                        "",
                        "",
                        itemcost.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        litemcost.ToString("C2")
                    },
            };

            //totlal class

            model.Total = new List<List<string>>()
                {
                     new List<string>()
                  {
                        "Total",
                        "",
                        "",
                        total.ToString("C2"),
                        "",
                        "",
                        ltotal.ToString("C2")
                    },
                };

            model.SecondTital = new List<List<string>>()
                {
                     new List<string>()
                     {
                      "Valuation - Off Site Parts"
                     },
                };
            foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
            {
                model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()
                    {
                        s.Name,
                        "",
                        "",
                        "Average Cost",
                        "",
                        "",
                        "Average Cost (With labour)"
                    };
                model.OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>()
                    {
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Parts",
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "",
                            "600000 series",
                            osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "600000 series",
                            osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            ""
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "",
                            "700000 series",
                            osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "700000 series",
                            osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            ""
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "",
                            "800000 series",
                            osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "800000 series",
                            osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            ""
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Tools",
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                             "",
                             "",
                            osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),

                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "",
                            "900000 series",
                            osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "900000 series",
                            osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            ""
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "",
                            "Other",
                            osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "Other",
                            osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            ""
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Components",
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiLoCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Items",
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                            "",
                            "",
                            osiLoItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                        },
                    };
                model.OffReporTotal = new List<List<string>>()
                    {
                        new List<string>()
                            {
                                "Total",
                                "",
                                "",
                                osiTotal[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                                "",
                                "",
                                osiFltotal[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                            },
                    };

            }
            model.osiGrandTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "OSI Grand Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ostotal.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    ofltotal.ToString("C2")
                },
            };
            models.Add(model);
        }
        return models;
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much for that Bill! I'm currently just getting an error message when I try to "return View(x)" it says cannot implicitly convert "system.web.MVC.ViewResult to <myProgram.Models.SummaryReportModel" you know why this is? Sorry if it's a silly question I'm just new to MVC and having struggles

Comment: I know before when it was "return model;" that it was returning the model but how do I do it for a list?

Comment: I need to see the controller. The way I did it's returning a view called "getMyTables" and passing x to the view. The controller's return type is ActionResult yours may be different. Can you post the whole controller?

Comment: Okay I posted the whole controller.

Comment: @chris OK in this case all you need to do is change private SummaryReportModel GetSummaryReport() {} to private List<SummaryReportModel> GetSummaryReport(){} so that it returns the list to the index controller. I assumed that you where populating the model inside your controller...I'll have some time when I get done with work to re-write my answer so you can just copy it into your project. Your so close...you just need to loop over the site collection and for each iteration add a new SummaryReportModel() to a List<new SummaryReportModel> then return the list.

Comment: @chris updated my answer to reflect your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your view, because the @cell is quite enigmatic but you can't just have a foreach in the view and expect to submit a collection.
Your fields need to be named like site[0].name = ...
Use a for loop for that and make sure the fields in the generated html have the attribute name like

```
site[0].sitename= ...
site[0].reporttitle =...

site[1].sitename= ...
site[1].reporttitle =...
```